# Dispalying Edges information when mouseover leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, geojson, folium

I have already (receive) an html page with leaflet map. I would like to display edges (links) informations when mouse over(or hover?). I can get the data from html-javascript via the following command `Roads.toGeoJSON().features

```
Roads.eachLayer(function (layer) {
            layer.on({
              'mouseout': function(){
                  layer.setStyle({fillColor: colorscale(mydata.speed)})
            },
              'mouseover': layer.bindPopup(layer.feature.properties.edge_id)
          })
        });
```

where `Roads` equal to `geo_json_118de89d5f914e07964f4fe5889a9bb6` which is defined as

```
var geo_json_118de89d5f914e07964f4fe5889a9bb6 = L.geoJson(null, {
                smoothFactor: 1,
                onEachFeature: geo_json_118de89d5f914e07964f4fe5889a9bb6_onEachFeature,
            
                style: geo_json_118de89d5f914e07964f4fe5889a9bb6_styler,
        });
```

For better understanding here is an example of the html file https://jsfiddle.net/5ptfuqk9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `L.Tooltip` is very helpful for this case. By default it is only displaying on mouseover. [Doku](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#tooltip)

```
geo_json_6e3c60c8b0b046c1a06eb56942730a3a.eachLayer(function (layer) {
            layer.bindTooltip("Id "+layer.feature.properties.edge_id)
        });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/7esauf9q/

Comment: Thanks,  That's what I am lookinng for